# jQuery faded bubble div blocking inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I have transparent, absolutely positioned hint boxes showing over a table of html inputs. When I fade them out with jQuery .fadeOut(200) , the inputs that were underneath are rendered unclickable.

After zooming the browser in and out, they are ok again. Is there a way to fix this without using zoom or refresh ?

Comment: can you reproduce them in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Maybe try calling .hide() on them in the complete event of fadeOut?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out that I was toggling two css classes: 'hidden' and 'showing', which changed css display property of popover boxes. After changing this to jQuery fadeIn() and fadeOut() everything works like a charm